# Which user license is used for Lightning External Apps and Lightning External Apps Plus?

Tags: experience-cloud, external-app

Looking at https://www.salesforce.com/eu/products/platform/pricing/lightning-external-apps/, there's the ability to create what seem to be 'lite' versions of Communities; which I'd be keen to understand more by developing a proof of concept in a Salesforce dev org.

I can see that there is a 'External Apps Login' user license available but does that apply to the cheaper Ligthning External App or the App Plus? I was expecting to see 2 user licenses similar to Customer Community Login and Customer Community Plus but I only see 1 license.

Comment: Given the naming conventions with Community and Community Plus with and without Login, I'd say (my assumption) "External Apps Login" applies login-based licensing (rather than member licensing) for "External Apps" rather than "External Apps Plus". I do, however, note that the page you reference mentions login and member licensing for both External Apps and External Apps Plus.

Comment: Thanks - I just found https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5 which outlines this too. What's odd now though is that I don't see 'External Apps' as a user license in a Salesforce dev org...

Comment: You'll need to ask Salesforce Support about provisioning appropriate licenses to allow you to investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be mindful of SKU vs License

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

The SKU 'Commerce Portal SKU' resolves to 'External Apps' License and is a high-volume license (i.e. same sharing approach as Customer Community (sharing-sets).

The SKU 'External Apps SKU' resolves to 'Partner' License'

You will see Licenses in your org, not SKUs.

A license is login if it has 'login' in the term, if it has nothing it is a member license

For differences between PRM SKU & External Apps SKU and Commerce Portals SKU and Custom Community SKU, focus on the Extra Data Storage and API Calls rows in the table

hth

Comment: That's all very helfpul but I'm still clueless how I can test out the External App license. Despite enabling Digital Experiences and Commerce Cloud in my dev org, I still do not see 'External App' license; which is what I'm expecting to see.